# Reporting services -- Export excel with data

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report showed as bar chart in sql server reporting services. when I export it to excel from the reporting services web interface, the exported file doesn't contain any data, it only has a bar chart image. Is there any way to make it export to excel with data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that if you want to include data in your Excel sheet, you'll have to include it somewhere in the report layout in a table or matrix, along with the chart.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155976(SQL.90).aspx, here is the reference I found. This is in the reference "Charts are rendered as pictures, not Excel charts. A chart is rendered the same way as an image element. " thanks for the answer
"